# Accessing Function from WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure WebApp and an Azure function App running in premium app service. Both have VNET integration with an Vnet hosting the Database.
My WebApp has public access but the function app should only be triggered from the Webapp and not publicly.
How can I restrict access to the function app? Will a service endpoint be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put them into different subnets, WebApp(Public), Function(Private) and then configure [NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-network-security-group) rule to allow incoming traffic only from subnet where you have WebApp and deny any other access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the Azure Function is configured, you should be able to use the Networking > Access Restrictions on your App Service. For details, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions